# Using Service Principal in Azure Devops Pipeline to run jobs

Tags: azure-devops, databricks, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to create a Pipeline in Azure Devops to run a job on Databricks. With my token from my account on Databricks it works ok, but I want the Service Principal to be used, not my private token.
So I created a Service Principal, added it to the Databricks instance in the Azure Portal and gave it the Contributor role. Unfortunately, I tried various ways to authenticate with SP in the .yaml file, but unfortunately it fails.
I am uploading an excerpt of the code for which my authentication for the private token works:

```
          - bash: |
              find $(bashHome) -type f -exec chmod u+x {} \;
              cat > job-params.json << EOF
              {
                "param1": "$(PARAM1)",
                "param2": "$(PARAM2)"
              }
              EOF
              cat job-params.json
              echo "DATABRICKS JOB NAME: $(DATABRICKS_JOB_NAME)"
              RUN_ID=$($(run_databricks_sh) $(DATABRICKS_JOB_NAME) job-params.json)
            env:
              DATABRICKS_HOST: $(DATABRICKS_HOST)
              DATABRICKS_TOKEN: $(DATABRICKS_TOKEN)
```

How should it be correctly to authenticate with SP? Or is it even possible?
Thanks sincerely in advance.

Comment: Hi @jbtt, may i know if there's any update? You can follow the steps below for a check, let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

> How should it be correctly to authenticate with SP? Or is it even possible?

Yes, you can use the Azure Service principal to run the databricks job.

Steps below:

1. Create an Azure Resource manager service connection from DevOps, it will automatically create the azure service principal for you, click the `Manage Service Principal` link, it will redirect to the azure page for the detials. Or you can manually create the service principal from Microsoft Entra ID, it works as same.

[image]

2. Add the service principal to databricks:

[image]

3. Go to the target databricks job -> Job details -> Edit permissions -> add `Can Manage run` for the service principal.

[image]

4. In your azure pipeline yaml, you can [get the access token for service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/sp-aad-token)(the resource ID is `2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d`), and use it for databricks cli. Detail yaml as below:

```
variables:
  armConnection: ARMConn1
  resourceID: 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d
  resourceGroup: yourRG
  databricksName: wadedatabricks1

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(armConnection)
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |    
     # Generate AAD Access Token for Azure Databricks service.
     $token = (az account get-access-token --resource $(resourceID) --query "accessToken" --output tsv)
     Write-Host "AAD Access Token: $token"
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=tokenvalue]$token"

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'run Databricks Notebook'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: | 
      databricksUrl='https://adb-58xxxxx.6.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0'
      requestUriRunnow="$databricksUrl/jobs/run-now"

      body='{
        "job_id": 59xxxx11561,
        "notebook_params": {
            "x": "30",
            "y": "50"
          }
      }'
      # Make the API request
      curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(tokenvalue)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$body" "$requestUriRunnow"
```

[image]